# multiple cells with nested IF statements that need to be in one calculation

Tags: excel

I have two cells(`B2` & `B7`) that could be multiple values. If `B2` & `B7` are any of those numbers it will reference value in `G7` that will be use in a calculation.

I have tried using just `IF` statements, `IF/AND` statements, and `IF/OR` statements

```
 =IF(AND(B7={0.6,0.65,0.7,1,1.04,1.07,1.16,1.5})*(AND(OR(B2={0.6,0.65,0.7,1,1.04,1.07,1.16,1.5}))),"100-(((F7-108)*5)+(G7*1)")
```

Ideally the calculation will be a whole number

Comment: Right now, this question sounds like you're just asking for an equation without any effort on your side of things. What equations have you tried? What is the issue? Is there are error message (if yes, please add) and/or is the result not as expected (if yes, what are you getting and what do you expect to get) ?

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
=IF(AND(OR(B2={0.6,0.65,0.7,1,1.04,1.07,1.16,1.5}),OR(B3={0.6,0.65,0.7,1,1.04,1.07,1.16,1.5})),100-((F7-108)*5)+(G7*1),"WHAT TO DO IF FALSE???")
```

Not sure what result will be when first conditions are not met, but you can replace as needed.